# extract substring using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, linux

I am trying to extract substring like ***.ini from string. 
For example, I have

```
000012: 378:210 File=test1.ini  Cmd:send command1 
000512: 3378:990 File=test2.ini  Cmd:send command2 File=not.ini Cmd: include command
```

I need to extract the substring after the first "File=", and the substring after the first File=***.ini which is "Cmd: ..." till the end.

So the result I want is:

```
test1.ini
Cmd:send command1
```

and

```
test2.ini  
Cmd:send command2 File=not.ini Cmd: include command
```

I tried:

```
re.match("(.*) File=(.*).ini(.*)Cmd:(.*)", line, re.M\re.I)
```

this works well with the first line, but for the second line,
I get:

```
test2.ini  Cmd:send command2 File=not.ini  #which is wrong, wanted is: 

test.ini

Cmd: include command
```

Anyone please help. Thanks.
LJ

Comment: The source of your problem is the `(.*)` This will greedily capture everything up until the last match of the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with `re.findall` function:

```
\bFile=(.+?\.ini)\s+(Cmd:.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO8jC4/1)

**Code:**

```
p = re.compile(ur'\bFile=(.+?\.ini)\s+(Cmd:.*)')
print re.findall(p, input_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

.* is too greedy, also there is no need to match from start of line.  Try this

```
re.search("File=([^\.]+.ini).*?(Cmd:.*)", line).groups()
```